# Format dates in DD/MM/YYY for multiple date selections in calendar picker view(Android)

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, calendar

I have a calendar picker where I am able to select multiple dates.I havebutton below to display the dates I have selected.But I am getting the dates in the format **[MON OCT 12 00:00:00 GMT+530, FRI OCT 16 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015, SAT OCT 17 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015]**.But my requirement is to get the dates in the following format **12/10/2015, 16/10/2015 ,/17/10/2015**.How can I achieve the same?
Thanks in advance.
Below is the code I used

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monthly_planner, container, false);
    Calendar nextYear=Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    calendar=(CalendarPickerView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
    Date today=new Date();
    calendar.init(today,nextYear.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today).inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
   // calendar.highlightDates(getHolidays());
    dropdown=(Spinner) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.monthly_planner_spinner);
    String[] items1 = new String[]{"Select Something"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items1);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
    button= (Button) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.action_next);
    Button button1=(Button) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.btnconfirm);
    datesSelected = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Order_ConfirmationActivity.class));
        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Date>selectedDates=(ArrayList<Date>)calendar
                    .getSelectedDates();
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedDates.toString(),
//                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String dates=selectedDates.toString();
            SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            for (int i=0;i<dates.length();i++)
            {
                 date[i] = df.format(dates);
            }
          for (int i=0;i<date.length;i++){
              datesSelected.setText(date[i]);
          }
        }
    });
    return rootView2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply formatting on Date object and **not String object**, like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // 12/10/2015
```

So, in your case, you have arraylist of dates in selectedDates, you need to format date objects in this arraylist. And please note the format : dd/MM/yyyy (capital M). For more formats, check Date and Time patterns in [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[UPDATE] I guess you are using `CalendarPickerView` allowing to select multiple dates, which you are retrieving by `calendar.getSelectedDates()` and then trying to display multiple dates in `datesSelected` (TextView). You may try the following:

```
ArrayList<Date>selectedDates = (ArrayList<Date>)calendar.getSelectedDates();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
for(int i = 0; i< selectedDates.size(); i++)
{
   Date tempDate = selectedDates.get(i);
   String formattedDate = sdf.format(tempDate);
   datesSelected.append(formattedDate);
   //Following if is added to avoid adding comma after the last date.
   if(i != selectedDates.size() -1)
   {
     datesSelected.append(",");
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi,can you show me how parse the dates in arraylist in my code..I am new  t android.Thanks in andvance

Comment: @a3.14_Infinfity :Thank you so much...it worked fine for me..Thanks a lot again..:)

Comment: @AmitNair: Glad it helped. You could consider upvoting/accepting this answer then. :)

Comment: I already have..it will  be  automatically upvoted once i get 15 reputation ..:)